# Adding a UISwitch to a UINavigationItem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem, uiswitch

I want to have a UISwitch in the right corner of a UINavigationItem, instead of a UIBarButton. Is this possible without subclassing the UINavigationItem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view inside it by using the [`initWithCustomView:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithCustomView%3a) method. For example:

```
UISwitch *switch = ...;
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:mySwitch];
```

Set this as the left/right item on your `UINavigationItem`.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible with `[UIBarButtonItem initWithCustomView:]`:

```
UISwitch* switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
UIBarButtonItem* switchItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:switchView];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = switchItem;
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift-

Write this code in viewDidLoad()

```
let switchDemo=UISwitch(frame:CGRectMake(15, 15, 0, 0))
        switchDemo.on = true
        switchDemo.setOn(true, animated: false)
        switchDemo.addTarget(self, action: "switchValueDidChange:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        self.view.addSubview(switchDemo)
```

And this is your func -

```
func switchValueDidChange(sender:UISwitch!)
{
if (sender.on == true){
println(“on”)
}
else{
println(“off”)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with `[UIBarButtonItem initWithCustomView:]`:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: mySwitch];
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift 4:

```
@IBOutlet weak var hostGuestSwitchOutletDeclare: UISwitch!
private func loadHostGuestSwitch(){
    hostGuestSwitchOutletDeclare.isOn = true
    hostGuestSwitchOutletDeclare.setOn(true, animated: false)
    hostGuestSwitchOutletDeclare.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchValueDidChange), for: .valueChanged)
    if self.hostGuestSwitchOutletDeclare.isOn {
        self.navigationItem.title = "ON"
    } else {
        self.navigationItem.title = "OFF"
    }
}
@objc func switchValueDidChange(sender:UISwitch!) {
    if (sender.isOn == true){
        self.navigationItem.title = "ON"
    } else {
        self.navigationItem.title = "OF"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Version**

```
let customSwitch = UIBarButtonItem(customView: UISwitch())
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customSwitch
```

Do this in viewDidLoad